# Not able to access a vector from private data section?

Tags: c++, class, random, vector, private

I have a C++ assignment to create a more random random number generator in C++. specifics can be found:http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/97056/ .

I'm getting an error message every time I try to access the vector in the private data section, and I can't figure out why?

I am also using complex Double and Integer classes that we created separately.

Header file:

```
 #ifndef RANDOM
 #define RANDOM

 #include "Double.h"
 #include "Integer.h" 
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>


 const int VECT_SIZE =250;
 const int PERCENT = 225;

 class Random
 {
 private:
     std::vector<double> vect(int(VECT_SIZE));
     void fillVect(double min, double max);
     void shuffle();

int index;

 public:
     Random(); // Default constructor 
     Random(double min, double max); 
     Random(Double min, Double max);
     Random(int min, int max); 
     Random(Integer min, Integer max); 

     Random(int seed); //seed the random number generator
     int nextInt(); // Returns the next random number as an int
     double nextDbl(); 
     void setRange(double min, double max); 
     Integer nextInteger();
     Double nextDouble();

 };
 #endif
```

Parts of main class that seem to have errors:

```
 void Random::fillVect(double min, double max)
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < VECT_SIZE; i++)
         {
    this->vect.push_back((((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX)*(max - min)) + min);

 }
shuffle();

 }
 void Random::shuffle()
 {
     index =0;
     for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
     {
         int r = rand() % VECT_SIZE;
         this->vect.push_back(vect[r]);
     } 
 }
```

Parts of main class that seem to have errors:

```
 Random::Random(double min, double max)
 {
     vect.clear();
     fillVect(min, max);
 }
```

Parts of main class that seem to have errors:

```
 double Random::nextDbl()
 {
     if(index>PERCENT)
     {
         this->shuffle();
     }
     index++;
     return this->vect[index];    
 }
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and listen to them.

Comment: Please reduce this blob of code to a [mcve].

Comment: When I change the vector in the data section to: std::vector<double> vect; , I get no errors when I build, only when it runs, and when I do get errors they all seem to be with accessing vect, like I said. I am "listening" as best as I can.I will try to edit down, but it's difficult when I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Your declaration of `vect` is currently that of a function taking an `int` and returning a `vector<double>`. Most (all?) good compilers should issue a warning about this, along with a possible solution.

Change the declaration to this:

```
std::vector<double> vect = std::vector<double>(int(VECT_SIZE));
```

Comment: @juanchopanza OMG I completely blanked on that, thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by taking an int? I had no error on that line before, when I try your first line of code I get an error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" and when I try your second I get no error, but that line is the thread breakpoint when I try and run it. I'm using XCode, if it helps at all.

Comment: @Io-stream The second didn't work because `vector` has an initializer list constructor and the first was also an error because I forgot it's in-class initialization. This one should resolve the error, although any runtime errors are a horse of a different color. And I mean that it is read as `std::vector<double> vect(int VECT_SIZE);` which is a function declaration.

Comment: Well, that did resolve the compiler error, but I'm still getting runtime errors on that line. I'm sorry I don't have more input, I'm fairly new to this...

Comment: Okay, I think I understand how it's being misread as a function, but if I simplify the line to 'vector<double> vect;' I get breakpoints in all the same places (listed in initial question), I thought it was because I didn't have a set size for the vector, but adding the size only gave me more errors.

Comment: This is the exact same question? I get errors when I try to access vect. I'm getting "bad access" errors in all the functions I mentioned. Same question. If you need more info, tell me what info you need. That doesn't change the question

Comment: @Io-stream You had compilation errors, and now you have runtime errors. I don't see how those are the exact same thing.

Comment: "I get no errors when I build, only when it runs, and when I do get errors they all seem to be with accessing vect" very first comment I made, elaborating on the situation.